# Форматированная строка из списка netstat -antp

Tags: linux, регулярные-выражения, grep

Мне нужно получить из:

```
netstat -antp | grep sshd
```

вот такую строку:

```
<ip> <status>
```

Максимум, чего я смог достичь, это вот это:

```
netstat -antp | grep sshd | grep -oE '([1-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}'
```

На данный момент не могу разобраться с дубликатами ip адресов и получением статуса (например, "ESTABLISHED").

Comment: Не совсем понимаю для чего регулярные выражения тут, посмотрите на вывод команды `netstat -antp | awk '/sshd/{print $5,$6}' | sort -u -t':' -k1,1` Выведет уникальные адреса и их статус. Возможно следует дополнить вопрос, тем что есть и как должно выводиться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
netstat -atnp | sed -n -r '/sshd/s/.*:[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9\.:]+):[0-9\t ]+(ESTABLISHED|LISTEN|TIME_WAIT).*/\1 \2/p' | sort -uV
```

Как это работает:

-Переводим `sed` в `silent` режим ключем `-n`, добавляем ключ расширенных регулярных выражений `-r`

-Выбираем строки только с `sshd`

-Далее выражение замены: `.*:[0-9]+[ \t]+([0-9\.:]+):[0-9\t ]+(ESTABLISHED|LISTEN|TIME_WAIT).*`, берем все символы до первого `:` c последовательностью чисел и любого количества пробелов и знаков табуляции после, этим исключаем список локального подключения, далее берем последовательность из цифр, точки и двоеточий и вносим это в группу, оставляя последнее двоеточие и последовательность из цифр(предположительно порт) за пределами группы, как и любое количество пробелов и знаков табуляции. Во второй группе указываем статусы которые нужны, перечисление их осуществляется через pipe `|` если нужно исключить или добавить в дальнейшем по аналогии, вне группы оставляем любые символы после.

-Выводим на печать группы `\1 \2`, ключем `/p` в конце команды. Если нужно поменять разделитель, к примеру на `~` поставить символ между группами `\1~\2`

-После выполняем сортировку результата, исключая дубликаты, в примере указана строка полностью, но можно ограничить строку, к примеру `sort -u -t' ' -k1,1` ключ `-t` указывает разделитель для сортировки, ключ `-k` позиции для сортировки

Answer (score 1):

Данные из табличного представления проще всего "выкусывать" при помощи `awk`, дубликаты можно убрать при помощи сортировки с удалением дубликатов (`sort -u`)

```
# netstat -antp | grep sshd | awk '{gsub(":[0-9]+?$","",$4); print $4," ",$6}' | sort -u
10.0.0.1   LISTEN
2001:258:1f0a:1880::   LISTEN
2001:258:70c8:1::1   ESTABLISHED
2001:258:70c8:1::1   LISTEN
125.21.8.62   LISTEN
```

Если вам нужны только ESTABLISHED строки, то это решается добавлением ещё одного `grep`:

```
# netstat -antp | grep sshd | grep ESTABLISHED | awk '{gsub(":[0-9]+?$","",$4); print $4," ",$6}' | sort -u
2001:258:70c8:1::1   ESTABLISHED
```

Comment: Эти команды выводят локальный IP, а как получить внешний IP? (p.s следующий IP в колонке)

Comment: Не уверен, что понял вопрос...

Comment: @Sheridan Скорее всего имелось ввиду выводить не 4 столбец,а 5.

Comment: Ну, в таком случае в строке $4 нужно просто на $5 поменять...

Comment: Впрочем, если нужны не только ESTABLISHED, то строка совсем чуть чуть другая, так как нужно откусить ещё и `:*`: `netstat -antp | grep sshd | awk '{gsub(":[0-9\\*]+?$","",$5); print $5," ",$6}' | sort -u`

Comment: *Useless use of grep* если уж пишите на awk, так не разменивайтесь на дополнительные вызовы shell.

Comment: Честно говоря, не вижу смысла особого. Использование только awk заметно увеличит сложность разработки скрипта, но не даст заметного бенефита.

Comment: Заменить `grep` на `/pattern/` — это сложно?! Про бенефиты сами подумайте, а то так и будем для hello world 4Гб оперативной памяти требовать и пятиядерного процессора.